# Facebook SDK 3 EOFException

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, eofexception

I am using the new FaceBook SDK 3.0. While posting images from the URL to "me/photos", I am intermittently getting an `EOFException`. I am getting this error once in a while (~1 in 20 times).

I must also add that just after getting the `EOFException` if I retry the posting again, it posts successfully.

So, for the time being I have coded to automatically retry one more time if I get `EOFException` and the solution seems satisfactory.

But I need to know what is causing it, Is it a bug in Android SDK. I Googled about it a lot but could not get anything.

I'm posting the logs (removing my access token and image URL for security reasons)

```
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611): Request:
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   Id: 9
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   URL:https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?caption=abc&format=json&sdk=android&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121026&access_token=ADBCEFG&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test.test%2Ftest%2Ftest%2F201695%2Ftest%2F18629
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   Method: POST
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   User-Agent: FBAndroidSDK.3.0.0
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   Content-Type:   multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   Parameters:
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):       caption:    abc
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):       format: json
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):       sdk:    android
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):       migration_bundle:   fbsdk:20121026
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):       access_token:   ABCDEF
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):       url:    http://test.test.test/test/test/201695/test/18629
06-05 15:09:42.585: D/FacebookSDK.Request(16611):   Attachments:
06-05 15:09:42.600: D/FacebookSDK.Response(16611): Response <Error>: java.io.EOFException
```

Comment: Had an error like this too in Spring Android. Had to do with something about http.keepalive property of the System class. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: In this case, EOFException means there is no more data to be read, which (again in this case) can only mean that the file is empty.

Comment: Any one find solution for this error?

Comment: I've also coded a retry when error.getErrorMessage().contains("EOF"), i think that it is a bug in ice-cream-sandwich, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24672

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you are "POST"ing to "me/photos"? Might just be a corner case or glitch when uploading. Had a lot of them.

Comment: Hey @napkinsterror I posted this so long ago, so now I have no idea about my question.,

Comment: Okay sorry. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: if it is not worth an answer, please vote to close it.

Comment: It would help to show how your handling the OutputStream logic. It might be more descriptive to see if your byte buffers are being handled correctly, or if there is an issue with the Dalvik trying to GC the bytes your reading within your while loop. (This can sometimes be an issue with how the code is compiled for performance. So if you don't want to share here, you can check the decompiled code in your IDE to see if the compiler made some 'helpful adjustments')

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

This is a `HttpURLConnection` related issue. The actual socket used for the connection is selected from a pool. Most servers create persistent connections (`Connection: Keep-Alive` header) in order to reuse existing sockets which is cheaper than creating a new one every single time. The problem comes from the fact that these sockets are open for a certain period of time, mostly 60 seconds or so, then they are closed and cannot be reused. The Android OS, however, tries to use the same socket as it thinks that the socket is still good since it was assigned to the same host, so it starts sending packages waiting for ACK and other response packages, which never come since the socket is not open anymore, though it's been expecting some answer, hence the `EOFException`.

### The solution

#### Step 1 - Limit the pool size to a relatively small number

```
private static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5;
// ...
static {
    System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", String.valueOf(MAX_CONNECTIONS));
}
```

#### Step 2 - Implement a retry mechanism

Wherever you use the Facebook code and get an `EOFException`, wrap it in a try-catch that catches the exception and retries connecting to the URL up to the max pool size. Here's a method stub, that could be used (*I don't know the Facebook SDK, hence the `TODO`'s*):

```
private void connect(int retryNumber) {
    try {
        // TODO your facebook code goes here
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        if (retryNumber > MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
            // TODO handle exception, it's over the limit, so it is a different problem
        } else {
            // TODO disconnect first, if possible
            connect(retryNumber + 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO other exception handling
    } finally {
        // TODO disconnect, if possible
    }
}
```

*Of course, you have to call this method with 0 retryNumber (`connect(0);`) the first time.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be having some internet connectivity issues.

You could write to some retrylogic to handle this exception by having it submit again, or see if the class you're using to upload has a way to increase the timeout for the transaction!